# Indexing error with variables

Tags: python, indexing

```
#Dancing Text :D
listinput = raw_input("Input text(usually between 1-10 letters ")
dance_time = raw_input("Alternate How Many Times? ")
listinput = list(listinput)
length = len(listinput)
alternate = 0
counter = 0
first_input = listinput
swap_counter = 0
tempchar = ""
counter = int(counter) #Just to make sure...getting errors

#above are just defining variable types and changing types to lists.

while counter <= length:
    if alternate == 0: #first, third, fifth character
        alternate = alternate + 1
        counter = counter + 1
    elif alternate == 1: #second, fourth, sixth character and so on....
        tempchar = listinput[counter]
        tempchar = str(tempchar)
        tempchar = tempchar.swapcase()
        listinput[counter] = tempchar #It should be the number 1 the first time it runs, but it gives a index error.
        alternate = alternate - 1
        counter = counter + 1

while swap_counter <= dance_time:
    print first_input
    print input
    swap_counter = swap_counter + 2
```

This is the error -

line 20, in module

tempchar = listinput[counter]

IndexError: list index out of range

I looked up indexing errors, and '1' should be in the range of the list, (I enter 'hello' whenever I test it)

If I'm understanding this correctly, the 20th line, when it runs should be "listinput[1]", the variable 'counter' being 1, since it's only looped once.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are assuming list's indexes start with 1. Actually they start with 0. So if you have one item in your list list[0] will give you that item.

So, to be able to execute

```
tempchar = listinput[counter]
```

you would have to be sure that

```
counter < length
```

is true, which isn't the case here, because counter can be equal to length.

Comment: Thank You! I was aware that indexing started at 0, I just forgot to take that into account while doing the <= sign. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `dance_time` is a string. Please use `swap_counter <= int(dance_time):`

A couple if things might be helpful:

You dont need a tempchar. You can convert the code:

```
    tempchar = listinput[counter]
    tempchar = str(tempchar)
    tempchar = tempchar.swapcase()
    listinput[counter] = tempchar
```

to the singlr line:

```
    listinput[counter] = str(listinput[counter]),swapcase()
```

Notice that you are just swaping the case of alternating characters depending upon the value of `alternate`. I am guessing that although this is set to `0` in this example, in a real program, you will want to change that at will. Then, you can try the following:

```
for i, l in enumerate(listinput):
    if   alternate == 0:  
        if i%2 == 1: # odd samples
            listinput[i] = str(listinput[i]).swapcase()
    elif alternate == 1:  
        if i%2 == 0: # even samples
            listinput[i] = str(listinput[i]).swapcase()
    else:
        pass
```

Or simply:

```
for i, l in enumerate(listinput):
    if (alternate+i)%2 == 1: # odd samples
        listinput[i] = str(listinput[i]).swapcase()
```

which is the same thing, assuming that `alterante` is either `0` or `1`, which can be easily checked with an `if` condition before.

Finally, notice that functions in Python are first-class values. So you can also return a function, and use that as a condition, like so:

```
def evenOdd(alternate):
    if   alternate == 0:  return lambda x: x%2 == 1
    elif alternate == 1:  return lambda x: x%2 == 0

print [  (l.swapcase() if evenOdd(alternate)(i) else l) for i, l in enumerate(listinput) ]
```

This is a teenie bit easier to read...

Again here, I have kept things simple. YOu will probably want to `raise` a `ValueError` within the `evenOdd` function if alternate is anything other than `0` or `1`.

Finally, following the above example, you can also do:

```
[(l.swapcase() if (i+alternate)%2==0 else l) for i, l in enumerate(listinput)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that later on.